# Setting style margin-top through inline code in partial view in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am looking to set margin-top attribute through inline code in my partial view in mvc4 something like below

```
<%
Dim top As Integer = -
marginTop As String = top.ToString() + "px"
%>

<ul style="margin-top:'<%: marginTop%>'">
```

Comment: what is the problem then?

Comment: It's not working. margin-top is not set when page renders. I don't know what's going wrong in this.

Comment: is it marg or marginTop in ul?

Comment: Ohh I mistyped it here only, It's not in the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix it should be done like below

```
<% Dim top As Integer = -425
Dim marginTop As String = "margin-top:" + top.ToString() + "px"
%>

<ul style='<%: marginTop %>'">
```